# point-of-sale-api iOS callback from FileMaker Go

Tags: filemaker, square, square-connect

I'm close to getting my homegrown POS app to work with Square, but I'm missing something simple and can't seem to turn up an answer. I'm using FileMaker Go as the app, but I don't think that that is relevant to my current proof-of-concept issue. It may be relevant to other issues later (callbacks).

In my point-of-sale-api settings, I have:

```
com.filemaker.go.17
```

for the Bundle ID, and

```
create-workflow
```

for the iOS App URL Schemes, which seems to be the first piece of code that Square allows me to save. Any prefixed item such as shortcuts://create-workflow gives an error without description (I'm hoping that Square will trigger a workflow as a test in this POC).

I'm hoping to just trigger safari or workflow/shortcuts with the callback as filemaker go doesn't directly accept the callback response without a helper application - which I'll eventually try.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Thanks tons!

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do. The Square Point of Sale API will allow you to take a payment from your custom app by opening the POS application with certain information. It sounds like you've already saved your bundle ID and URL Schemes in your Square Developer Dashboard, so are you experiencing an issue when trying to take a payment?

Comment: Hi sjosey - thanks for the reply.

Yes, trying to get FileMaker Go to process a payment using the Square App and hardware. I've gotten past the first few errors about authorizing my app in the square developer portal (bundle ID, app key, etc), but I can't find a good example of what kind of data is acceptable in the iOS URL Schemes.

From what I've read, FM Go cannot parse the callback data from Square, so another app has to do it for it. I'll cross that bridge next - just trying to get Square to receive the payment info at the moment.

Comment: So currently have you gotten to the point of actually initiating a transaction (step 5 here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/setup-ios)? If so, are you receiving an error?

Comment: I'm getting an error that states:
API ERROR The iOS Callback URL Scheme does not match the one in your application settings. Check your application's Point Of Sale API Settings.

Comment: It sounds like you've inputted a different URL Scheme inside your code then what you specified in your dashboard. Please take a look at a sample application here, with instructions about how to set it up in your dashboard: https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS/tree/master/Examples/HelloCharge-Swift